# Print event severity in sentencecase: log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I want to print the event severity in sentence case, in the logs instead of default Uppercase. I have modified the log4j2 xml like below,

```
 <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT" direct=true>
          <PatternLayout pattern="%level{WARN=Warning, DEBUG=Debug, ERROR=Error, TRACE=Trace, INFO=Info}"/>
 </Console>

<Loggers>
 <AsyncRoot level="INFO" includeLocation="false">
   <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT">
 </AsyncRoot>
</Loggers>
```

Current Event Severity Printed in Logs :

- INFO / WARNING / DEBUG / ERROR / TRACE

Expected Event Severity Printed in Logs :

- Info/ Warning / Debug / Error / Trace

I still see the event is getting printed in Uppercase in logs. Something else need to be changed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my reading of the `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.LevelPatternConverter` [source code](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/2acc7801c5b226c363c992ab0b41ce079808de58/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/pattern/LevelPatternConverter.java#L62), Log4j2 *should* output the level replacement strings *exactly* as you gave them in the pattern.

If that's not happening, check that Log4j2 is actually using that config.

If that doesn't resolve the problem, you may need to use a debugger to figure out what is going on.